# VS Code not indicating that method does not exist in Angular template

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

If I write a method name in angular template (HTML) that doesn't exist in angular component, the method is not underlining in the template. It should warn me that `save()` doesn't exist. I'm using Angular 11 and VS Code, and I have seen this functionality somewhere.

How can I make the underline show in VS Code when the method in the angular template doesn't exist?

```html
<button (click)="save()">Save</button>
```

Comment: Hi Naveed. What's your question about this? Are you asking how to get the underline to show? If so, please can you edit your question to clarify that, and to provide details of what IDE you're using?

Comment: Hello @Tim. I have updated the question.  Yes, how to get underline if a method does not exist in the component?

Comment: I don't use VS Code so I can't give a good answer to this, but I suspect you might need an extension to get this behaviour. This one looks like a good possibility - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template - but I can't make any promises.

Comment: I already have this extension.

Comment: Do you have `strictTemplates` set to true in your `angularCompilerOptions`? (This seems to be recommended on the homepage for that extension, you can set it in `tsconfig.json`.)

Comment: Basically, I had this extension before but I was not sure about the feature it has. secondly, I have uninstalled a lot of extensions, due to which Angular language service is working fine now, and methods are underlined if not exist in the component. and this is the extension you recommended in the above link. 
Thank you so much @Tim , my issue is resolved now. 
strictTemplates is not needed for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install this vscode extension [Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template).